# Does there exist a arbitrary function $f_n(x)$ such that $\max(f_i(x)-f_j(x))=1$ for every $n≥i,j≥1$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a continuous function defined in terms of $x$ and $n$ for $n \geq 1$ and $0 \leq x \leq 1$ such that the functions of any two different $n$ values could be plugged into $\max(f_i(x)-f_j(x))$ such that the answer is $1$?

I have messed around with piecewise functions, sine and cosine functions, and many different options but have come up empty-handed. I think the best way is to somehow make $f_i(x)$ always equal $1$ and $f_j(x)$ always be $0$, but I cannot figure out how to do that for an arbitrary $n$.

Comment: You have no restrictions of continuity, so such a construction seems very much possible.

Comment: @ReverseFlow Thank you, I meant for it to be a continuous function and have edited my post appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of $n>1$, take
$$
f_{k} \equiv \boldsymbol{1}_{A_k}
\qquad \text{where} \qquad
A_k \equiv \left(\frac{k-1}{n},\frac{k}{n}\right].
$$
Then, assuming $i \neq j$,
$$
\max\left(f_{i}(x)-f_{j}(x)\right)=f_{i}(i/n)-f_{j}(i/n)=1-0=1.
$$

**Addendum**: Since you added the restriction of continuity after I answered, I'll just mention that you can replace the indicator functions with [tent functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function) to get the same result.

**2nd Addendum**: If you want ($C^\infty$) smoothness, you can [mollify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier) the indicator functions in the original construction (Caveat: You should use a mollifier whose support is small enough).

Comment: parsiad, something about your comment doesn't add up....also, now there is a continuity restriction....

Comment: @ReverseFlow: For each pair $i \neq j$, you just need a point where exactly one function is equal to 1 and all the other functions are equal to zero. That's all that's happening in my construction. Also, you can swap out the indicator functions for tent functions to achieve continuity.

Comment: That works. Unless there is a storm and the tents....no, but seriously, that works.